# What are these SOT23 components in this RPM gauge circuit?

Tags: identification, alternator, rpm

I'm trying to work out the input portion of the input circuit on a digital RPM gauge. It accepts a W input from a standard automotive alternator.

[image]

I can't identify the JCL446 which only uses two of its pins, the 2TC or the E4ED diodes. What are the SOT23 ICs likely to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The JCL446 is most likely a diode (or dual diode) of some flavor or another

While I cannot find an exact match for the JCL446 in the SMT codebooks I checked -- JC seems to map to a BAW56 dual diode or a BAL74/BAR74 diode, and this would be consistent with only two pins of the component being used, as well.  I would verify this theory with the second JCL part extending off the bottom right of your photo, though.  (It's also consistent with the part having a reference designator of "D3" on the board's silkscreen.)

### The 2T is pretty definitely a MMBT4403 PNP transistor

According to [multiple](http://www.comchiptech.com/cms/UserFiles/MMBT4403-G%20RevB296064.pdf) [datasheets](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MMBT4403-D.PDF), the 2T top mark is used for the MMBT4403 PNP small-signal transistor -- if it checks out as a PNP, then it's pretty definitely a MMBT4403.

### And the E4's are pretty definitely MMZD5234 zeners

Again, according to [multiple](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/MMSZ5221-MMSZ5261(SOD123).pdf) [datasheets](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds18010.pdf), the E4 top mark is used for the MMZD5234 6.2V zener diode. (If it's a Diodes Inc part, for which the full top marking scheme is an exact match, then the "ED" is a date code for December 2017.)

Answer (score 0):

I also came here looking for a SOT23-3 diode marked "JCL44L". I believe it is onsemi BAT54S. The important part of that marking is "L44".
https://web.archive.org/web/20211030052757/https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Schottky-Barrier-Diodes-SBD_onsemi-BAT54S_C258194.html

[image]